# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:/XLRI/Term-4/ML'

Tags: python, permissionerror

I am new to Python. I am facing a permission error while writing a new CSV file. I tried opening the app as an administrator, but the error persists.

The line of code which generating the error and the error itself are:

```python
kdta=pd.DataFrame(kdta)

kdta

kdta.to_csv("D:/XLRI/Term-4/ML")

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:/XLRI/Term-4/ML'
```

### Additional Details

- working in Spyder
- Python is Anaconda distribution
- running in Administrator account

Comment: is ``D:/XLRI/Term-4/ML`` by any chance an existing directory? You need to specify a file path, not a dir path. Try ``D:/XLRI/Term-4/ML/my_file.csv``

Answer (score 0):

Write permissions are needed in order to create a file in a folder.

If you are in Linux/Mac try `chmod +w D:/XLRI/Term-4/ML` (maybe you need `sudo`).

Also, it could be that the folder `ML` is from another owner. In that case you should try: `chown -R $USER:$USER D:/XLRI/Term-4/ML` (maybe you need `sudo`)

If you are in windows there are several ways to allow a folder to be written in. Check out this link: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fix-access-denied-folders-windows-10/

Comment: Hi Hope
Thanks for your answer. The name file was missing in my code. It's corrected. Thanks for your support

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought the file was called ML. Glad you fixed it. If my answer did help you in any way, don't forget to upvote it! Thanks.